# Limit number of available SharePoint Themes

Tags: sharepoint-server

Is it possible to limit number of Themes that user (Including Site Owner) can apply on SharePoint site? Can we restrict user to apply only selected themes and disable rest of them? ( under Site Settings >> Web Designer Galleries >> Themes )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the user’s permissions on the Composed Look to hide this look (theme) for the user.

1. Go to "Composed looks" list: Site settings -> Web Designer Galleries -> Composed looks
2. Select a composed look item and click "Shared with" menu from Item tab on the ribbon. Click “Advanced” to navigate to item permission page.
3. Stop inheriting permissions by clicking “Stop Inheriting Permissions” on the ribbon. Then grant the unique permissions on this composed look item.

After that, only users has permissions on this composed look (including admins) can view and apply this look on Site settings -> Look and Feel -> Change the look.

Comment: You can delete the composed look item

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. Can we hide those themes for admins also? For normal users (with Design permission) it works fine, but I also want to hide these option for Site Owners.

Comment: Thanks,,, deleting specific composed look item worked...... Cheers!!!!!